# Can't get Google One Tap Sign In for Android working with OAuth tokens

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, google-oauth, google-signin

I have been struggling with implementing Google One Tap Sign in. I can get it to store usernames and password but I can't get it to work with a Google token. I use Back4App (Parse) as my database.

I have followed the guide from Google: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials  as well as the Back4App one: https://www.back4app.com/docs/platform/sign-in-with-google

I have gotten the id and idToken values and I can see I'm getting the values ( I setup a web OAuth client). The problem I've got is I get a Back4App failure each time saying "Google auth is invalid for this user."

With the below code block I have tried passing the hashmap values as id_token and id etc, same result.

```
oneTapClient = Identity.getSignInClient(this);
    signInRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
            .setPasswordRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.PasswordRequestOptions.builder()
                    .setSupported(true)
                    .build())
            .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                    .setSupported(true)
                    //new B4App web client id
                    .setServerClientId("xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                    // Only show accounts previously used to sign in.
                    .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                    .build())
            // Automatically sign in when exactly one credential is retrieved.
            .setAutoSelectEnabled(false)
            .build();

    oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<BeginSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(BeginSignInResult result) {
                    try {
                        startIntentSenderForResult(
                                result.getPendingIntent().getIntentSender(), REQ_ONE_TAP,
                                null, 0, 0, 0);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't start One Tap UI: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    // No saved credentials found. Launch the One Tap sign-up flow, or
                    // do nothing and continue presenting the signed-out UI.
                    Log.d(TAG, "One Tap Failure: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }); 

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //get result code back from Facebook if they were authenticated correctly, and let Parse know
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 10:
            try {
                SignInCredential credential = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(data);
                String idToken = credential.getGoogleIdToken();
                String username = credential.getId();
                String password = credential.getPassword();
                if (idToken != null) {
                    // Got an ID token from Google. Use it to authenticate
                    // with your backend.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got ID token.");

                    Map<String, String> authData = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    authData.put("id", username);
                    authData.put("access_token", idToken);

                    Task<ParseUser> parseUserTask = ParseUser.logInWithInBackground("google", authData);
                    parseUserTask.continueWith(new Continuation<ParseUser, Void>() {
                        public Void then(Task task) throws Exception {
                            if (task.isCancelled()) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Task cancelled");
                            } else if (task.isFaulted()) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Save FAIL" + task.getError());
                                //Toast.makeText(context,task.getError().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                // the object was saved successfully.
                                ParseUser user = (ParseUser) task.getResult();
                                Log.w(TAG, "Success " + user.getObjectId() + " " + user.getUsername() + " " + user.getEmail() + " " + user.getSessionToken());

                            }
                            return null;
                        }
                    });
                }
                else if (password != null)
                {
                    // Got a saved username and password. Use them to authenticate
                    // with your backend.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got password.");
                    parseLogin(username, password,0);
                }
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, Objects.requireNonNull(e.getLocalizedMessage()));
                //Toast.makeText(context,e.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]